Why does the sum give a different result when i add values and change the num variable from int to long data type
I've been trying the cs50 credit problem and i am stuck in the part where you add every other digit in the number. This is what i came up with.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 123456789;
    int sum, last, second;
    while (num>0)
    {
        last = num/10;
        second = last%10;
        num /=10;
        cout<<second<<endl;
        
        sum += second;
        num /=10;
    }
    cout<<"sum: "<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}

Output:
8
6
4
2
0
sum: 20

It works and gives the sum of every other digit which is 20 in this case. But it gives a very different answer when i add more values and change it to long.
This is where it gives a different result.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long num = 123456789;
    long sum, last, second;
    while (num>0)
    {
        last = num/10;
        second = last%10;
        num /=10;
        cout<<second<<endl;
        
        sum += second;
        num /=10;
    }
    cout<<"sum: "<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}

Output:
8
6
4
2
0
sum: 140736744828580

The answer should be 20 but it gives a really big number. I think the problem is my computation in the while loop but I can't seem to find a solution which is why I posted it here. Thanks in advance.

The variable sum is uninitialized. So the statement sum += second; invokes undefined behavior.

Please use warning flags -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic to catch this kind of mistakes early: https://godbolt.org/z/8eGqMevhK

AFAIK, CS50 does not cover C++. C++ is not C.

After fix it works as expected with both types: https://godbolt.org/z/TMMee8oEP

In this line (1st version):
int sum, last, second;

as well as in this line (2nd version):
long sum, last, second;

sum is uninitialized.
It is also not initialized further on, and then when this line is executed:
sum += second;

You cause Undefined Behavior (UB).
When UB happens, the C++ standard explicitly makes no guarantees about how the program will behave, so there's no point in reasoning about it.
The fact that with the int version you got correct result is a matter of pure chance.
In order to fix it you simply have to initialize sum (in my opinion it is best to define it in a separate line and initialize):
int/long sum = 0;



@JeremyFriesner I meant that it is valid to do anything after UB in a sense that it doesn't violate the standard, but maybe it wasn't clear. I guess you could also say that it is invalid in a sense that with UB nothing is guaranteed. Not sure which is the better phrasing.

Maybe you could say something like "When UB happens, the C++ standard explicitly makes no guarantees about how the program will behave, so there's no point in reasoning about it".  It's a difficult subject to describe :/
